# ios- Date class have different value from dateString in swift

Tags: ios, swift, date

Below is the code in question:

```
func calendar(_ calendar: JTAppleCalendarView, didSelectDate date: Date, cell: JTAppleCell?, cellState: CellState) {
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy MM dd"
    print("The selecting part")
    print(date)
    print(date.dateTimeString())
}
```

and the output I have is:

> 2018-05-31 15:00:00 +0000
>
> Jun 1, 2018 at 12:00:00 AM

I do not know where 2018-05-31 15:00:00 +0000 is coming from, where it should be 2018-06-01.

I wonder if it's an internal error. Could someone supply me with a fix?

Comment: Try setting the time zone : 
`formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier:  TimeZone.current.identifier)`

Comment: I tried but that didn't fix anything..

Comment: What is `dateTimeString()`? What's the code for that?

Comment: date is a Date() class and dateTimeString() is an attribute of the Date class

Comment: Try this : dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")

Comment: `dateTimeString` is not standard Date API method, it's custom extension somewhere in your codebase. Explore it's behavior to get answer, or provide it here if you still have questions. Also your formatter have no effect on `date`, and maybe on `dateTimeString` (I hope :) ).

Comment: Your code is fine. The output is fine. `2018-05-31 15:00:00 +0000` is the output of `print(date)`. The `+0000` means UTC time. This is how `Date` objects appear when you print them. It's the same moment in time of `Jun 1, 2018 at 12:00:00 AM` if you live in the UTC+9 timezone.

Comment: Please read the info at http://www.maddysoft.com/articles/dates.html to better understand Date.